# parameterized query not passing values to $row array

Tags: php, mysqli

First time poster here.  I have a php login script, but my SQL Query won't pass any values to my $row array.

```
<?php

require 'functions/security.php';
require('db/connection.php');

session_start();
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($results = $db->query("SELECT userID, username, password 
                              FROM users
                              WHERE username = ?")){
        if($results->num_rows) {
            $results->bind_param('s', $username);
                $results->execute();
                    while($row = $results->fetch_row()) {
                        $userID = $row[0];
                        $dbUsername = $row[1];
                        $dbPassword = $row[2];
                    }
                    $results->free();
        }
    }


    if($username == $dbUsername && password_verify($password, $dbPassword)) {
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
                    header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        echo "<h2>Oops!</h2>";
    }
}
?>
```

I have been looking at documentation for bind_param for a while;  I'm pretty new to php so it's likely that I'm missing something silly, but I can't for the life of me figure out what.

EDIT
Ok whoops I wasn't fetching the result.  That solves that.  Thanks!

```
<?php
    require('db/connection.php');
    session_start();
    //if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = "MYUSERNAMEFORTESTINGPURPOSES";
        $password = "MYPASSWORDFORTESTINGPURPOSES";


        $stmt=$db->stmt_init();
        $stmt->prepare("        SELECT userID, username, password 
                                FROM users
                                WHERE username = ?");
                    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($userID, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
                    //WOOPS WASNT FETCHING RESULT
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                       printf("%s %s %s", $userID, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
                   }

        if($username == $dbUsername && password_verify($password, $dbPassword)) {
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
                        header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            echo "<h2>Oops!</h2>";
        }
    //}
    ?>
```

Comment: Which SQL and tools do you use? Could you please add this info?

Answer (score 1):

You don't `query` and `execute` together. That `query`  in your case should be `prepare`

```
db->query("SELECT userID, username, password FROM users WHERE  username = ?");
```

Should be

```
$stmt =  $db->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("SELECT userID, username, password FROM users WHERE  username = ?");
```

**[Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php)**

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I gave it my best shot and implemented your suggestion, but it still won't bind the results to the strings I requested.  I'll post the edit in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`stmt` is the object returned from when you `prepare()` the query using the connection.

```
$conn= $db->stmt_init();
$stmt= $conn->prepare("SELECT userID, username, password 
                      FROM users
                      WHERE username = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($userID, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);

if($stmt->fetch()) {//notice you dont need a loop for single row
   printf("%s %s %s", $userID, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
}
...
```

Comment: `$db` an `$conn` don't match